# Looking for online resources to learn about the Midot

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, middos-character-traits

I want to work on my middot. I'm already learning Mussar and am now in search of the teachings of *pinimiut* referencing the 13 Attributes and also the characteristics that reside within, namely 7 nations that invaded Israel and their respective klippot.

Comment: One works on Midot by working on Midot and studying works of Mussar, not by learning Kabbalah.

Comment: @N.T. - and doing in addition to learning. I made a list / taxonomy of some of the more central Mussar practices at http://aspaqlaria.aishdas.org/2008/07/18/mussar-tool/

Comment: So I think I found it on my own - 
https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380693/jewish/Vanquishing-the-34Lower-734-22.htm

Comment: I updated your question to reflect your comments. You can [edit] further or rollback my changes

Comment: [The Elucidated Tomer Devorah](https://a.co/d/fW2ULQ0) is a very accessible elucidation of the 13 attributes according to the Ramak, R Moshe Cordovero, in the first chapter of his book *Tomer Devorah*

Comment: @mbloch thanks for demonstrating that there are indeed good and valid kabbalistic works to form an approach of studying the topic the OP is looking for. Chabad.org is good, more on what you want, JSarai, e.g. on the 7 nations: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379644/jewish/Evil-Among-the-Nations.htm. https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379644/jewish/Evil-Among-the-Nations.htm, and more, and there are the footnotes to the original maamarim and sefarim. Knowing the inner side of what one is studying is vital for deep thinking individuals nowadays, don't be put off.

Comment: @mbloch if you've read the Elucidate Tomer Devorah, can you confirm if it is a faithful translation, or does it skip all the Kabbalah like similar Feldheim/Artscroll books?

Comment: @RabbiKaii there is not much kabbala in there. It is a simplification (I called it elucidation), not a translation. If someone wants real deep authentic Kabbala in English I would look at http://www.urimpublications.com/shomer-emunim-the-introduction-to-kabbalah.html but is another level of complexity - and not directly connected to the OP's question